# Как сделать возврат данных только при определенном условии?

Tags: функции, kotlin

Возник вопрос, есть ли возможность вернуть данные из функции только при определенном условии, т. е.:

```kotlin
fun foo(): Int {
    if (условие верно) {
        вернуть число
    }
    здесь я не хочу возвращать, т. к. не получаю то, что возвращаю сверху
}
```

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Каков смысл такого странного желания?

Comment: Что должно происходить вместо возвращения?

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну, у меня получалось то что если я все таки возвращаю в конце число предварительно создав переменную сверху чтобы она была видна, то когда я функцию вызывал в нее так раз таки записывалась эта переменная не переписанная в условном типе. Но все равно спасибо, буду пытаться сделать по-другому.

Comment: Чего вы хотите добиться? Какая вообще задача?  Если вы в месте вызова ожидаете целое число, а туда ничего не придет, то что будет?

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов, 1. Возвращать null, 2. кидать исключение, 3. поменять архитектуру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишете, что ничего не хотите возвращать, давайте рассмотрим варианты, как это можно сделать:

1. Сделать так, чтобы программа зависла:

   ```kotlin
   fun foo(): Int {
       if (условие) {
           return число
       }
       while(true) {
           // Никогда не выходим из цикла, программа зависает
       }
   }
   ```
2. Сделать так, чтобы программа завершилась с ошибкой:

   ```kotlin
   fun foo(): Int {
       if (условие) {
           return число
       }
       throw Error("Не знаю что вернуть, поэтому просто упаду")
   }
   ```
3. Поменять тип на `Int?` и все-таки вернуть, но пустоту (null):

   ```kotlin
   fun foo(): Int? {
       if (условие) {
           return число
       }
       return null
   }
   ```
4. [Частый кейс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в программировании, если вы хотите сообщить потребителю функции `foo`, что ее используют неправильно, то делайте так:

   ```kotlin
   fun foo(): Int {
       if (!условие) {
           throw IllegalStateException("Сейчас не то состояние, чтобы меня вызывать")
       }
       return число
   }
   ```

   То же самое, но более красиво, с помощью стандартной функции [check](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html):

   ```kotlin
   fun foo(): Int {
       check(условие) { "Сейчас не то состояние, чтобы меня вызывать" }
       return число
   }
   ```